# Mouse middle button function

Tags: mouse, opera

I have the [ABBYY Lingvo 12](http://www.abbyy.com/support/lingvo_12) translater. It make translate word by push middle button of mouse and it's working perfect! But when I try to translate word by it way in Opera browser I have scrolling instead translate.
How can to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps,it may not work as you stated .. 
in browser, if you set your cursor upon a link, and then click middle button, it's "Open New Tab" function.

I kindly want to advise to choose Babylon Dictionary and translator

Best.

Answer (score 0):

From the "Main functionality of the program" section at [the support pages](http://www.abbyy.com/support/lingvo_12_kb): *The pop-up translation function works in Microsoft Office applications and in Internet Explorer.*

> Question: Why doesn’t the pop-up translation function work?
>
> Answer: To use the pop-up translation function, make sure ABBYY Lingvo 12 is running at the moment you want to use the function. Go to Tools -> Options -> Translation -> Look-up from other applications, and make sure the option "Show pop-up translation" is selected.
> The pop-up translation function works in Microsoft Office applications and in Internet Explorer. If you experience problems, try restarting ABBYY Lingvo 12. Select "Translate", then click "Exit". Pop-up translation doesn’t work in PDF files, so use hotkey translation instead.

But there's hope:

> To use the hotkey translation function, select the corresponding option in Tools -> Options -> Translation -> Open a full entry.

Comment: I need exactly the "open a full entry" function and hotkey translation is working for it, but mouse middle button much faster and more convenient